# How to cache images using volley

Tags: android, android-volley, image-caching, imagedownload

I am using Volley Library for my app. I want to cache images to memory and also use diskcaching for some of data required for further processing. The problem I am facing is, all the available links talks abt direct image url passed:
NetworkImageView imgAvatar = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
imageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);

but in my case I dont have the URL of the Image. Can some one please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It may be easier to use something like http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: `but in my case I dont have the URL of the Image`, so what do you have?

Comment: I have a common URL not specific to one image.

Comment: Have you tested requests to that Url by some tools such as Postman yet? Pls post your screenshot and the Url (if this Url is available in Internet) so that we can check more

Comment: I am sending an xml to url in which i specify the image_id..